# Why Android Studio Virtual Device have been this

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I updated Android Studio from 1.4 to 2.0. When I ran the AVD, it showed up like this:

[image]

What happened? And what should I do to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Could you remove all AVD device and recreate it ? I recommend  you should use Genymotion to make AVD.

Comment: I had do that.I had remove All,had edit config ,had change API,but all  actions did not work./(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

Comment: Simply use Genymotion, Its a third party Emulator, you have to download it from: https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

Comment: Becaus the studio2.0 have a new property:Instant Run.It sine to must use the Android Studio AVD or one  reality Phone.So....I want to solve the proleam.If nobody can solve that,I have to use Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why, it was because I had checked Enable Device Frame.

[Screenshot - Click image to view full size.[image: Screen shot of Android Virtual Device (AVG)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IELO4.png)